# Don't both 關心 and 在意 mean the same thing?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I recently learned a sentence: 大家都和關心也很在意這件事

However, don't both 關心 and 在意 mean the same thing -- to care about? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "大家都很關心也很在意這件事"

When two different words have a shared definition, they can be used interchangeably in some context. See my answer to this question:  [Are there any two chinese words which can be used interchangeably?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/39579/are-there-any-two-chinese-words-which-can-be-used-interchangeably)

> 關 = relate; 心 = heart

> 關心 : to be concerned; to worry about; **care about**

~

> 在 = in/at/on; 意 = mind

> 在意 : take notice of; **care about**; take to heart

If they can be used interchangeably, then you can also use them concurrently, to make them reinforce each other as synonyms

Example:

"大家都很**關心**也很**在意**這件事" "Everyone **cares about** and **take notice of** this"

The subtle difference:

- 關心子女安危 (concern about the safety of one's children) expresses a more serious manner than  在意子女安危 (care about the safety one's of children)
- 我不在意浣熊在我後園出沒。 (I don't care about raccoons coming and going in my backyard.) expresses a more casual manner than 我不關心浣熊在我後園出沒。 (I am not concerned about raccoons coming and going in my backyard.)